# Sort div alphabetically when clicked

Tags: html, css, json, grid

I have a grid which has five columns. Is there a way to sort the columns when a the particular heading is clicked? For example, when name is clicked, the columns are sorted in ascending order and vice versa. I am not using tables. All the data is displayed using divs`

```html
<div class="Table" id="tab">
    <div class="Title">
        <p>Financial data</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Heading">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Plan</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Forecast</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Best Case</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Commit</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Structure to display the JSON Data-->


    <div class="Row">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p id="country_name1"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p id="plan_1"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell">
            <p id="forecast_1"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="col3" class="Cell">
            <p id="best_case1"></p>
            <p class="ftype" id="best_case1.1"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="col4" class="Cell">
            <p id="commit1"></p>
            <p class="ftype" id="commit1.1"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can this be done using javascript or jquery? [image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with different plugins, for example:

**TinySort** (rewritten in pure Javascript, compatible with divs)
http://tinysort.sjeiti.com

**Datatables** (jQuery)
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

**Tablesorter** (jQuery)
http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Other examples on Tympanus
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/10/03/33-javascript-solutions-for-sorting-tables/

Comment: Yea but I do not have table tags. I have divs

Answer (score 1):

You can keep it in an array and then you can use sort, if you put all the names with the same class you can take it like

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("Name").innerHTML;
x.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a });

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("Name").innerHTML = x[i] ;
}
```